# How can I create Simple aspx webpage which will send me parameters in the link

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-applications

I am trying to do something from scratch  in asp

I would like to get something like below. From basic hard coded values.

```
http://localhost:2478/Default.aspx?phone=905123456&order=123456
```

After that I want to use this parameter in my variables for SQLquery

I am new to asp.net and vb , I'm learning. Can you please explain me in details? Any helps will be appreciate.

Can you please provide any basic code from where I can start

Comment: seems that it is web forms. but you tagged with asp.net mvc.

Comment: This is a good place to [**start**](http://www.dotnetperls.com/querystring). After which, [Give me parameterized SQL, or give me death](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)

Comment: @EdSF: I'll take cake :)

Comment: @EdSF: This link is for behind the page how can I create webpage wich send URL

Answer (score 0):

Based on your latest comments:

```
<form method="get" action="default.aspx">
   <input type="text" name="phone" />
   <input type="text" name="order" />
   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Key points:

- `method=get` (fields are in url instead of body)
- note that the form above doesn't have `runat=server` (more below) - it's a plain HTML Form on plain HTML page
- in the context of ASP.Net Web forms, you may run into issues particularly if you are using `Master Pages` (you can't nest forms, and a Master page is a container for your entire page).
- ASP.Net forms do `POSTbacks`  - re: `method=post`
- You can use/add plain forms in an ASP.Net page as long as you don't **nest** them (outside of the server side ASP.Net `form`).
- If you have no choice (e.g. Master Page),  you'll have to construct the Querystring manually after a POSTback, then `Response.Redirect` to some other target (adding the querystring manually).
- there are other non-ASP.Net-y ways of doing it - e.g. javascript, but that a different story

Comment: I successfully get the parameter's in the link..now i Would like to store those in variables how it possible.?

Comment: plz check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294314/how-can-i-create-sql-query-which-takes-parameters-from-url-in-asp-net-c-sharp